# C# Singleton thread safe

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

I have a singleton class similar to this

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton m_instance;
    private Timer m_timer;
    private static List<CustomObject> m_cacheObjects;

    private Singleton()
    {    
        m_cacheObjects = new List<CustomObject>();
        m_timer= new Timer(MyTimerCallBack, 
                           null, 
                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 
                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));           
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return m_instance;
        }
    }

    private void MyTimerCallBack(object state)
    {
        //******** Update the list by interval here ******************

        m_cacheObjects = UpdateTheList();
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
        foreach (CustomObject obj in m_cacheObjects)
        {
            // do something here based on obj

            // The question is, does the m_cacheObjects is thread safe??
            // what happen if the m_cacheObjects is changed
            // during the loop interation?
        }
    }
}
```

The CallMe method will be called by web service:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void CallMeWebService()
    {
        Singleton.Instance.CallMe();
    }
```

The questions:
1) Is the m_cacheObjects is thread safe? what happen if the m_cacheObjects is changed(because of the timer) during the loop interation (in the CallMe() )?

2) Is a new thread will be created when the Webservice CallMeWebService() is being called?

Comment: 1)a) No, 1)b) You can't be sure, 2) Yes

Comment: I will follow the below answers to make the static initialization to be thread safe.

Comment: Now i more concern about the static list m_cacheObjects. I implicitly pause (debug mode)in the foreach loop and wait for the timer to tick and change the m_cacheObjects list, supposingly the foreach loop will fail because of the modification of the list, but it continue looping without exception. Is this normal?

Comment: Just a FYI with all the locking: If `m_cacheObjects` is only modified by `MyTimerCallBack` (i.e all the other methods that access `m_cacheObjects` are `read-only`, it'd be a lot simpler just to `lock` `m_cacheObjects` during `MyTimerCallBack` which is called once a minute, rather than repeatedly locking and unlocking every time someone calls the `read-only` methods. To the best of my knowledge, locking for a read isn't essential, only when the state of the collection could change.

Answer (score 8):

1: No, a static list is not automatically thread-safe; you must protect `m_cacheObjects` manually

2: That is an implementation detail; at first glance it looks like it exposes itself as a sync method, but *how* it does that is entirely up to it

Actually, your static initialization isn't thread-safe either; I could brute-force a scenario where two different `Singleton` instances were used. It would take repetition to produce it, but it would happen.

Frankly, unless you have a really good reason not to, the simplest but safest singleton pattern is simply:

```
private static readonly Singleton m_instance = new Singleton();
```

Comment: @L.B. note I mentioned "simplest". To be frank, the situations that need a lazily initialized singleton are very rare; a: singletons should be rare, b: you'd need to know that `Singleton` was expensive to create, and c: you'd need to know that there are useful things that can be done *without* needing it. In this case, I think it actually fails all 3 criteria.

Comment: By manually, do you mean using the lock keyword or something else?

Comment: @Luis yes I do indeed mean "the lock keyword or something else" ;p obviously `lock` would be the simplest approach (and simplicity counts for a lot), but there are plenty of ways it could be done.

Answer (score 6):

```
//using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

private static volatile Singelton _instance;

public static Singelton Instance
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new Singelton();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Explain:

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` This will tell the compiler that the access to "Instance" is "Synchronized" so the system take care about the calls to this Parameter.

This is Thread-Safe.

EDIT:
(Also, the "Lock()" examples are not safe! Coz, u can disable the thread Safety with "Monitor.Exit(Singleton);")

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty good resource on how to implement the singleton pattern in a thread safe way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
     if (instance == null) 
     {
        lock (syncRoot) 
        {
           if (instance == null) 
          instance = new Singleton();
        }
     }

     return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

This simply makes sure that there will never be more than one instance. You also need to apply locking for your custom method.

```
public void CallMe()
{
    lock (syncRoot) 
    {
        foreach (CustomObject obj in m_cacheObjects)
        {
            // do something here based on obj
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter I don't mind a downvote if I deserve it, but would you please put a comment in along with it? As is it simply seems like one of the other answerers wanted to push me down the list of answers regardless of what I said.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you have aread on Jon Skeets article on how to create thread safe singletons over at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is not thread safe.

I believe i would use a **lock** in both 'MyTimerCallBack' and 'CallMe' methods

Answer (score 0):

1) No, `m_cacheObjects` is not thread-safe.

2) Yes, new thread will be created (well, it may not be new thread but rather thread taked from thread-pool).

You'll need to protect `m_cacheObjects` with `lock` statement. Also, in the CallMe method I'd recommend to create a local copy of `m_cacheObjects`:

```
// create new field syncRoot
private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
```

New CallMe method:

```
List<CustomObject> localCopy;
lock (syncRoot)
{
    localCopy = new List<CustomObject>(m_cacheObjects);
}

foreach (var nextObject in localCopy)
{
// Do some work
}
```

And updated `MyTimerCallBack` method:

```
lock (syncRoot)
{
    m_cacheObjects = UpdateTheList();
}
```

And please also implement thread-safe Singleton (read other answers for details).

Comment: i understand the new CallMe method.   but not sure about the MyTimerCallBack , if im sure that the m_cacheObjects will be updated before the next timer tick, do i still need to lock it?

Comment: Single `lock` statement doesn't make sense. By using `lock` in `MyTimerCallback` you can be sure that `CallMe` will wait until MyTimerCallback completes. And vise versa - lock in `CallMe` makes sure that `m_cacheObjects` won't be updated until it'll be copied to a `localCopy`.